# LUA - invalid value (table) at index 1 in table for 'concat'

Tags: lua

I’m trying to see the results of a csv to table conversion I found online by using the table.concat option, but I always get the error "invalid value (table) at index 1 in table for 'concat'"

Here is an extract of the source csv file..

```
created_at,entry_id,conservatory,kitchen,hallway,living_toom,front_room,lean_to,outside,cabin
2021-03-03 20:17:30 UTC,3986,18.5,21.1,20,20,19.4,16.6,7.7,10.10
2021-03-03 20:47:30 UTC,3987,18.5,21.1,20,20,19.3,16.6,7.5,9.80
2021-03-03 21:17:30 UTC,3988,18.5,21.1,20,20,19.4,16.4,7.2,9.80
2021-03-03 21:47:30 UTC,3989,18.5,20.9,20,20,19.1,16.2,7.1,9.60
```

and here is my code, what am I missing ?

```
-- csv to Lua table converter

local csv={}
for line in io.lines('/home/pi/shared/feed-watts-12h.csv') do
    table.insert(csv, {})
    local i=1
    for j=1,#line do
        if line:sub(j,j) == ',' then
            table.insert(csv[#csv], line:sub(i,j-1))
            i=j+1
        end
    end
    table.insert(csv[#csv], line:sub(i,j))
end

print(csv)

local out = table.concat(csv," - ")
print(out)
```

Full error message..

```
lua: home/pi/shared/convert_csv_to_table.lua:30: invalid value (table) at index 1 in table for 'concat'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'concat'
        home/pi/shared/convert_csv_to_table.lua:30: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
```

Comment: `concat` should be used only with tables of strings/numbers.  Your table is a table of tables.

Comment: Thanks @EgorSkriptunoff , is there a way to take a .csv and just have it in the one table ? So concat would work ?

Comment: You should `concat` each subtable separately.  `is there a way to take a .csv and just have it in the one table?` - do you really want to store the csv without splitting it in lines?

Comment: Yes, sorry I would want to have the csv split in to lines/rows as it is in .csv form. my overall objective is to extract specific from the .csv such as the first value, the last value of a particular column/row and then look at doing similar totals and averages etc.,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print that table for debugging purposes for example, just run a loop.

```
for _,line in ipairs(csv) do print(table.concat(line)) end
```

Reading that CSV would also be a good opportunity go make yourself familiar with string patterns and Lua's string library. It has much more to offer than `string.sub`.